# System log in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I made a bot in ruby, which plays a small online game. It was able to reach the final level and kill the final boss there. As the game ends there, my program reaches an unknown state and I receive an exception. However, I need some information from that battle (i.e. the final html pages). I can start all over again, but it takes around 10 hours until it reaches the final boss.

My question is: Is there some kind of a system log in Ruby, where I can see (interpolated, like `bash` invoked with `-x` option) the last few executed commands? I know that Ruby has such classes, but I haven't used them in my code, so I would like to know if there is something more general.

Comment: Is your ruby program calling shell scripts?

Comment: @nurettin No, it isn't. I added the `bash -x` only as a concrete example of what I have in mind.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no permanent log of stack in ruby, but perhaps there is a proxy in your network ? You could try isolating your URL downloads using its logs.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Logger class in the std lib:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html

But you'd need to have used it to begin with in order to get the log.

Answer (score 0):

You should use set_trace_func.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-set_trace_func

Comment: Can you provide an example, please?

Comment: The example is in the link.